# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null for the jpa saveAll

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am getting these error while integrating the spring-boot with JPA repository 
here is the code

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmpController {

    @Autowired
    private CrudRepo crud;

    @Autowired
    private AddrCrudRepo addr;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entity;

    //@Autowired
    //private ModelMapper mapper;

private static int count = 0;


    @Bean
    public ModelMapper model() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    //@Autowired
//  public EmpController(ModelMapper mapper) {
//      this.mapper = mapper;
//  }



    @RequestMapping(path = "/post-addr", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<AddressModel> postAddr(@Valid @RequestBody List<AddressRequest> addr1){
    //  crud.findById(id)

        //AddressModel list = new AddressModel();

        EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel();

        System.out.println("CALLING THE MAPPER "+addr1);
        List<AddressModel> addr_list = ObjectMapperUtils.mapAll(addr1, AddressModel.class);

        System.out.println("CALLED THE MAPPER "+addr_list);
        addr_list.forEach((a) -> {

            crud.findById(a.getEmpId()).ifPresent((b) -> {
                System.out.println(this.count++);
                a.setEmp_id(b);
                b.getAddress().add(a);

            });
        });


//      AddressModel addr_list = model().map(addr1, AddressModel.class);
//      
//      crud.findById(addr1.getEmp_id()).ifPresent((b) -> {
//          addr_list.setEmp_id(b);
//          
//      });`enter code here`
        System.out.println(addr_list.size());
        List<AddressModel> addr3 =  addr.saveAll(addr_list);
        System.out.println(addr3);
         return addr_list;

    }
```

getting an error in the `postAddr`  method  as when it returns the `List<AddressModel>` and here is the `AddressModel`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Emp_Address")
public class AddressModel  implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="address_id")
    @Id
    private Integer address_id;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="states")
    private String states;

    @Transient
    private Integer empId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="emp_id")
    private EmployeeModel emp_id;

    public AddressModel() {

    }

//getter and setter
```

and `EmployeeModel`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class EmployeeModel implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="Emp_id")
    @Id
    private Integer emp_id;

    @Column(name="Emp_Name")
    private String emp_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="emp_id")
    private Collection<AddressModel> address = new ArrayList<>();

    public EmployeeModel() {

    }

//getter and setters
```

so while saveAll is done properly but when the postAddr method returns the List it throws the StackOverflow

Comment: Are you printing the objects on console?

Answer (score 2):

This `StackOverflow` error is coming because generated `toString` methods of both classes are circularly dependent on each other.

`EmployeeModel` tries to print `AddressModel` but again `AddressModel` tries to print `EmployeeModel` and hence the error.

Try removing `AddressModel` from `toString` method of `EmployeeModel` class or reverse, remove `EmployeeModel` from `toString` method of `AddressModel` class.